# How to deal with array<String> in spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a json dataset, and it is formated as:

```
val data = spark.read.json("user.json").select("user_id","friends").show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             user_id|             friends|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|18kPq7GPye-YQ3LyK...|[rpOyqD_893cqmDAt...|
|rpOyqD_893cqmDAtJ...|[18kPq7GPye-YQ3Ly...|
|4U9kSBLuBDU391x6b...|[18kPq7GPye-YQ3Ly...|
|fHtTaujcyKvXglE33...|[18kPq7GPye-YQ3Ly...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [user_id: string, friends: array<string>]
```

How can I transform it to [user_id: String, friend: String], eg:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             user_id|             friend|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|18kPq7GPye-YQ3LyK...| rpOyqD_893cqmDAt...|
|18kPq7GPye-YQ3LyK...| 18kPq7GPye-YQ3Ly...|
|4U9kSBLuBDU391x6b...| 18kPq7GPye-YQ3Ly...|
|fHtTaujcyKvXglE33...| 18kPq7GPye-YQ3Ly...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

How can I get this dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat_ws(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) function to concat the array of string and get only a string

```
data.withColumn("friends", concat_ws("",col("friends")))
```

> `concat_ws(java.lang.String sep, Column... exprs)` Concatenates multiple
>   input string columns together into a single string column, using the
>   given separator.

Or you can use simple udf to convert array to string as below

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 val value = udf((arr: Seq[String]) => arr.mkString(" "))

 val newDf = data.withColumn("hobbies", value($"friends"))
```

If you are trying to get values of array  for user then you can use [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) method as

```
data.withColumn("friends", explode($"friends"))
```

> explode(Column e) Creates a new row for each element in the given
>   array or map column.

If you are trying to get only one data then, as @ramesh suggested you can get first element as

```
data.withColumn("friends", $"friends"(0))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to get only 1 friend in the friends in one row.

Comment: Where is explode function, how to find it in api?

Comment: you can find it here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html